# Add/remove custom stop words with spacy

Tags: python, nlp, stop-words, spacy

What is the best way to add/remove stop words with spacy? I am using [`token.is_stop`](https://spacy.io/docs/api/token) function and would like to make some custom changes to the set. I was looking at the documentation but could not find anything regarding of stop words. Thanks!

Comment: The complete list: `from spacy.en.word_sets import STOP_WORDS`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can edit them before processing your text like this (see [this post](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/364)):

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en")
>>> nlp.vocab["the"].is_stop = False
>>> nlp.vocab["definitelynotastopword"].is_stop = True
>>> sentence = nlp("the word is definitelynotastopword")
>>> sentence[0].is_stop
False
>>> sentence[3].is_stop
True
```

Note: This seems to work <=v1.8. For newer versions, see other answers.

Comment: Ah nice. Thank you!

Comment: This solution does not seem to be working anymore with version 1.9.0? I am getting `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @E.K. the reason for the error is because the vocab input word should be unicode (use u"the" instead of "the")

Answer (score 71):

Using Spacy 2.0.11, you can update its stopwords set using one of the following:

To add a single stopword:

```
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.Defaults.stop_words.add("my_new_stopword")
```

To add several stopwords at once:

```
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.Defaults.stop_words |= {"my_new_stopword1","my_new_stopword2",}
```

To remove a single stopword:

```
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.Defaults.stop_words.remove("whatever")
```

To remove several stopwords at once:

```
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.Defaults.stop_words -= {"whatever", "whenever"}
```

Note: To see the current set of stopwords, use:

```
print(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)
```

Update : It was noted in the comments that this fix only affects the current execution. To update the model, you can use the methods `nlp.to_disk("/path")` and `nlp.from_disk("/path")` (further described at https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading).

Comment: @AustinT It is syntactic sugar to obtain the union of two sets, `a|=b` being equivalent to `a=a.union(b)`. Similarly, the operator `-=` allows to perform a set difference. The curly bracket syntax allows to create sets in a simple way, `a={1,2,3}` being equivalent to `a=set(1,2,3)`.

Comment: This doesn't actually affect the model.

Comment: I mean that it actually doesn't seem to affect the current execution either. (Maybe I'm running something out of order.) The other method seems foolproof.

Comment: I concur with @fny. While this adds the stopwords to nlp.Defaults.stop_word, if you check that word with token.is_stop, you still get False.

Comment: Like others, I've found that this approach does not update `is_stop` 
e.g. nlp.Defaults.stop_words.add('foo'); nlp.vocab['foo'].is_stop returns False

Answer (score 20):

**Short answer for version 2.0 and above** (just tested with 3.4+):

```
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

print(STOP_WORDS) # <- set of Spacy's default stop words

STOP_WORDS.add("your_additional_stop_word_here")
```

- This loads all stop words as a set.
- You can add your stop words to `STOP_WORDS` or use your own list in the first place.

To check if the attribute `is_stop` for the stop words is set to `True` use this:

```
for word in STOP_WORDS:
    lexeme = nlp.vocab[word]
    print(lexeme.text, lexeme.is_stop)
```

In the unlikely case that stop words for some reason aren't set to `is_stop = True` do this:

```
for word in STOP_WORDS:
    lexeme = nlp.vocab[word]
    lexeme.is_stop = True
```

---

**Detailed explanation step by step with links to documentation.**

First we import spacy:

```
import spacy
```

To instantiate class `Language` as `nlp` from scratch we need to import `Vocab` and `Language`. Documentation and example [here](https://spacy.io/api/language#init).

```
from spacy.vocab import Vocab
from spacy.language import Language

# create new Language object from scratch
nlp = Language(Vocab())
```

`stop_words` is a default attribute of class `Language` and can be set to customize the default language data. Documentation [here](https://spacy.io/api/language#defaults). You can find spacy's GitHub repo folder with defaults for various languages [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/spacy/lang).

For our instance of `nlp` we get 0 stop words which is reasonable since we haven't set any language with defaults

```
print(f"Language instance 'nlp' has {len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)} default stopwords.")
>>> Language instance 'nlp' has 0 default stopwords.
```

Let's import English language defaults.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
```

Now we have 326 default stop words.

```
print(f"The language default English has {len(spacy.lang.en.STOP_WORDS)} stopwords.")
print(sorted(list(spacy.lang.en.STOP_WORDS))[:10])
>>> The language default English has 326 stopwords.
>>> ["'d", "'ll", "'m", "'re", "'s", "'ve", 'a', 'about', 'above', 'across']
```

Let's create a new instance of `Language`, now with defaults for English. We get the same result.

```
nlp = English()
print(f"Language instance 'nlp' now has {len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)} default stopwords.")
print(sorted(list(nlp.Defaults.stop_words))[:10])
>>> Language instance 'nlp' now has 326 default stopwords.
>>> ["'d", "'ll", "'m", "'re", "'s", "'ve", 'a', 'about', 'above', 'across']
```

To check if all words are set to `is_stop = True` we iterate over the stop words, retrieve the lexeme from `vocab` and print out the `is_stop` attribute.

```
[nlp.vocab[word].is_stop for word in nlp.Defaults.stop_words][:10]
>>> [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

We can add stopwords to the English language defaults.

```
spacy.lang.en.STOP_WORDS.add("aaaahhh-new-stopword")
print(len(spacy.lang.en.STOP_WORDS))
# these propagate to our instance 'nlp' too! 
print(len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words))
>>> 327
>>> 327
```

Or we can add new stopwords to instance `nlp`. However, these propagate to our language defaults too!

```
nlp.Defaults.stop_words.add("_another-new-stop-word")
print(len(spacy.lang.en.STOP_WORDS))
print(len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words))
>>> 328
>>> 328
```

The new stop words are set to `is_stop = True`.

```
print(nlp.vocab["aaaahhh-new-stopword"].is_stop)
print(nlp.vocab["_another-new-stop-word"].is_stop)
>>> True
>>> True
```

Comment: did that with version 2.0 and got "ImportError: No module named en.stop_words"...suggestions?

Comment: @user1025852 Unfortunately I cannot replicate your error. My code still works fine (now even using spacy 3.4.x).

Answer (score 5):

For 2.0 use the following:

```
for word in nlp.Defaults.stop_words:
    lex = nlp.vocab[word]
    lex.is_stop = True
```

Comment: You are showing how to fix a broken model as per [this bug/workaround](https://archive.is/HI5ZQ#selection-1231.0-1263.4). Whilst it is easy to adapt this for the OP needs you could have expanded on why you are writing the code this way: it is currently required because of the bug, but it's an otherwise redundant step, as `les.is_stop` should already be `True` in the bug-free future.

Answer (score 4):

This collects the stop words too :)

`spacy_stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS`

Answer (score 0):

In latest version following would remove the word out of the list:

```
spacy_stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
spacy_stopwords.remove('not')
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.3.0
If you want to replace the entire list instead of adding or removing a few stop words, you can do this:

```
custom_stop_words = set(['the','and','a'])

# First override the stop words set for the language
cls = spacy.util.get_lang_class('en')
cls.Defaults.stop_words = custom_stop_words

# Now load your model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

The trick is to assign the stop word set for the language before loading the model. It also ensures that any upper/lower case variation of the stop words are considered stop words.

Answer (score 0):

See below piece of code

```
# Perform standard imports:
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# Print the set of spaCy's default stop words (remember that sets are unordered):
print(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)

len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)

# Make list of word you want to add to stop words
list = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat']

# Iterate this in loop

for item in list:
    # Add the word to the set of stop words. Use lowercase!
    nlp.Defaults.stop_words.add(item)
    
    # Set the stop_word tag on the lexeme
    nlp.vocab[item].is_stop = True
```

Hope this helps. You can print length before and after to confirm.