# SpaCy custom stopwords not working properly

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, stop-words

There is ONE word not being recognized as stopword, despite being on the list.
I'm working with spacy 2.0.11, python 3.7, conda env, Debian 9.5

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.es.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
nlp = spacy.load('es', disable=['tagger', 'parser', 'ner'])
STOP_WORDS.add('y')
```

Doing some tests:

```
>>> word = 'y'
>>> word in STOP_WORDS
True
>>> nlp(word)[0].is_stop
False
>>> len(STOP_WORDS)
305
>>> [word for word in STOP_WORDS if not nlp(word)[0].is_stop]
['y']
```

So, from 305 listed in STOP_WORDS, one is not flagged as such. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't adding the word correctly, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380305/4623227)

```
word = 'y'
spacy.lang.es.stop_words.STOP_WORDS.add(word)
nlp.vocab[word].is_stop = True
```

That solved the problem

---

Old answer, didn't solve the problem

<strike>I found the cause.</strike>

I was getting a warning on importing spacy:

```
RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility.
```

Apparently this indicates a version mismatch. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845304/runtimewarning-numpy-dtype-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility/40846742#40846742)

> These warnings are visible whenever you import scipy (or another package) that was compiled against an older numpy than is installed.

In [spaCy GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2593) a numpy version was suggested. This ended up solving the problem:

```
conda install numpy=1.14.5
```